# Mobile app using Rhodes Framework

Tags: rhomobile

I want to build mobile app on rhomobile.com/Rhodes Framework. This is completely new for me. I just want to make small app will have following functionality.

1. The app will provide FB/Twitter Login.
2. Once login the user can take picture and upload to cloud db or mongo and simultaneously share on FB/Twitter wall.
3. Also i want analytic for this. So if anybody has an idea regarding this pls. help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how much details you are looking for, so here are some general information about what to do and references to the information you will need.

1) Login to Facebook/Twitter.

To provide FB/Twitter login you need to use the respective APIs. For FB I would suggest you take a look at their Mobile Web Tutorial (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/) or Authentication documentation (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) where it is described how you login.

2) Camera support and upload of photo to Facebook.

Providing camera support for your Rhodes application is quite easy and is described in the Device Capability section of the Rhomobile Documentation (http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#camera). They also have a code sample of how it works [here](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes-system-api-samples/blob/master/app/Image/controller.rb).

Once you have taken the picture you should be able to upload it through the image-uri which you get in the take_picture response.

How you can upload pictures to FB is described on their developer site. You can for example take a look at the following guide which is posted on FB - [How-To: Use the Graph API to Upload Photos to a user's profile](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498).

3) Analytics.

There are many ways to get analytic data about your application. One way would be to use Google Analytics (http://code.google.com/intl/da/apis/analytics/).

Comment: Thank you so much. It's really helpful. I will definitely work on it.

Comment: Sounds good. Just ask if there is anything else you need. But if you feel that you got your question answered, I would appreciate it if you accepted my answer. :)